# Run cron job every first minute of every hour

Tags: cron

I need to run cron job every hour at first minute

I have already tried the following   :

```
1>  0 * * * * ? *

2> 0 */1 * * * ? *
```

Unfortunately I did not get correct results

I need the job to start at first minute  for every hour as the following :

```
0:01
1:01
2:01
3:01
4:01
.
.
23:01

end
```

Comment: Ref https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: I think you're looking for this. [link](https://crontab.guru/#1_*_*_*_*). `1 * * * *` in the future, you should use backticks to denote code/cli operations.

Answer (score 2):

Every hour at minutes 1

```
 0 1 0/1 ? * * *
```

ref [Cron Expression Generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

[image: Ref cron expression]

Comment: @Cœur thanks for your advice, Will no longer be making a mistake